# How do we remove installed packages in damnsmalllinux distribution(debian)?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I'm currently running damnsmalllinux distribution and I want to remove certain packages from the desktop like the beaver but I can't locate package to in /etc/init.d/ to remove[image]

[image]

How do I remove the package called Beaver or axyFTP when I can't locate the package name to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, see my answer to [How do I find the installed package size in damnsmalllinux (debian)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201971) to restore `dpkg` functionality.

`/etc/init.d` doesn't contain desktop applications, it contains startup scripts for services. To remove a package for an application you don't need, have a look at the [list of packages in DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/packages.html); if you can find the package there,

```
dpkg --purge package
```

should remove it for you (assuming nothing else depends on it). Some applications in DSL aren't provided as packages though and can't easily be uninstalled; I get the impression this is the case for Beaver.

Comment: Okay thanks , I'm trying to remove firefox and its not listed in installed packages . What should I do?

Comment: That falls under the "can't easily be uninstalled" category I mentioned; you'd need to figure out which files correspond to Firefox and delete those manually.