# How do I find the installed package size in damnsmalllinux (debian)?

Tags: debian

How do I find the installed package size in damnsmalllinux (debian)?I tried every? I tried most the solution on the internet but I can't seem to find all the installed package size

```
 dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size;10}\t${Package}\n' | sort -k1,1n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its documentation, Damn Small Linux [strips `/var/lib/dpkg`](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/packages.html), and the files therein are necessary for `dpkg-query` to work (and for `dpkg` to be able to remove packages). You need to download [`dpkg.tar.gz`](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/dpkg.tar.gz) as indicated in the linked page to restore that directory. (Thanks to [clearkimura](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/125388/clearkimura) for the link!)

Once you've done that, the `dpkg-query` line you give in your question should work.